# How to print a 2d matrix and add labels while keeping everything centered (Python)

Tags: python, matrix

I have a confusion matrix and a set of labels that I want to be added on every line and column when printing

This is my code:

```py
def PrintConfusionMatrix(matrix,labels):
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        print(labels[i],end = "  ")#print labels on the first line

    for i in range(len(mc)):
        print("\n")
        print(labels[i], end = "  ")
        for j in range(len(mc)):
            print(matrix[i][j], end = "  ")
```

The inputs are as follow:

```py
labels = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
matrix = [[19,  0,  0],
         [ 0, 19,  0],
         [ 0,  2, 20]]
```

It currently prints this:

```py
Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica  

Iris-setosa  19  0  0  

Iris-versicolor  0  19  0  

Iris-virginica  0  2  20
```

but I want it to be printed in this way

```py
             Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica  

Iris-setosa       19              0               0  

Iris-versicolor    0             19               0  

Iris-virginica     0              2              20
```

Can anybody help me with this ?
Also it would be great if it could scale to bigger 2d matrix

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to use `pandas`, if you don't mind using an external library:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=labels, index=labels)

print(df)

                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa               19                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0               19               0
Iris-virginica             0                2              20
```